# PHP - Push to array without key

Tags: php

I'm trying to add some $_POST values to my $_SESSION array, but I can't seem to find the best approach.

Result with array_push():

```
array(1) {
  'product_ids' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "9"
    [1] =>
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      string(2) "14"
    }
  }
}
```

expected result:

```
array(1) {
  'product_ids' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "9"
    [1] =>
    string(2) "14"
    }
  }
}
```

Code:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['product_ids'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['product_ids'],$_POST['id']);
} else {
    $_SESSION['product_ids'] = $_POST['id'];
}
```

$_POST array:

```
array(1) {
  'id' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(2) "14"
  }
}
```

$_SESSION array:

Emtpy

Comment: You are trying to push *what exactly* into *what exactly*?

Comment: could you post your actual code? How array looks and how you trying to "push" to it?

Comment: Do `var_dump()` of the variables, and the actual code doing the push. Create a [mcve].

Comment: What is `$_POST['id']` exactly? From its name it should probably be a single number. From the looks of it it's an array though?

Comment: *Should* `$_POST['id']` be an array?!

Comment: @deceze Yes, i have to foreach trough the array so i can make GET requests to my API according to the ID's.

Comment: And sometimes the array contains more than 1 id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$_POST['id']` is an array of ids, it should be named `$_POST['ids']`. Use clear naming.

```
... else {
    $_SESSION['product_ids'] = $_POST['id'];
```

Initially you're creating `$_SESSION['product_ids']` as an array…

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['product_ids'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['product_ids'],$_POST['id']);
```

…you're then pushing an array as value into the existing array. You want to merge those two arrays into a new array instead:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['product_ids'])) {
    $_SESSION['product_ids'] = $_POST['ids'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['product_ids'] = array_merge($_SESSION['product_ids'], $_POST['ids']);
}
```

Comment: Or, with at least PHP 7.0, skip the conditional outright:  `$_SESSION['product_ids'] = array_merge($_SESSION['product_ids'] ?? [], $_POST['ids']);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it also possible to check if the id already exists in the session array?

Comment: @Frank `array_unique(array_merge($_SESSION['product_ids'], $_POST['ids']))`…